# Are "Concepts about Real" Concepts?

Tags: theravada, abhidhamma, reality, visuddhimagga, commentary

In Theravada, the Concepts are considered unreal ("person", "chariot" etc.). Then what about the "Concepts about Real" ("red", "perception")? Are they Concepts? or Real?

Comment: It is an important question that I have seen many Abhidhamma learners asking. It might at first glance, seem like a childish question, if you don't think about it properly.

Comment: Seems like useless conjecture and proliferation to think about this and it shows a fundamental misunderstanding of reality.

Comment: As an aside, in its form this question reminds me of the topic in Mathematics which asks something like, "Is the set of sets itself a set, and does it contain itself?" -- which can be paradoxical and discussed extensively -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set -- and I guess might be more-or-less related to the "completeness theorem". It's not a kind of topic that I've seen much of before on this site.

Comment: I'm not sure that "unreal" is the best translation. "conventions" might be closer to the purpose of the teaching.

Comment: There is a tendency in people who are already tired with worldly sciences, to think some important Abhidhamma thoughts as unnecessary or too mathematical. But it is not the case.

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to say, "Here is an important question, and here is my correct answer to that." Instead it's to ask other people to try to answer your question if there's something you don't know or want help with; and, to help answer questions posted by other people.

Comment: @Blake. Please stop spamming the front page with questions..

Answer (score -1):

Actually "Concepts about Real" are Concepts. They are called **"Vijjamana Pannatti"**. It is found in the Commentary.

> Conventional Reality is two-fold.
>
> 1. Nama Pannatti: Name of the Concept
> 2. Attha Pannatthi: Meaning(idea) of the Concept
>
> Nama Pannatti again is six-fold.
>
> 1. Vijjamana Pannatti : **Concepts about Real** (eg: blue, mind)
> 2. Avijjamana Pannatti : Concepts about Unreal (eg: person)
> 3. Vijjamanena Vijjamana Pannatti : "Concepts about Real" by "Concepts about Real" (eg: eye-consciousness)
> 4. Vijjamanena Avijjamana Pannatti : 'Concepts about Unreal" by 'Concepts about Real" (eg: blue-shirt)
> 5. Avijjamanena Vijjamana Pannatti : 'Concepts about Real" by 'Concepts about Unreal" (eg: mango-smell)
> 6. Avijjamanena Avijjamana Pannatti : 'Concepts about Unreal" by 'Concepts about Unreal" (eg: sissy-boy)
>
> [Conventional Reality is not Impermanent!](https://classicaltheravada.org/t/conventional-reality-is-not-impermanent/468)